# React Router: hashHistory appending query params doesn't rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently, I have a component with a handler that runs this:

```
_redirect () {
  hashHistory.push(`/somepath?a=1&b=2`)
}
```

The route component for `/somepath` is configured to grab the query params and store them in the state, as such:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      a: this.props.location.query.a || 5,
      b: this.props.location.query.b || -2,
    }
  }
```

If I'm currently on a different path, then things work perfectly. The problem I'm running into is that if I'm already in `/somepath` with no params and I execute the handler, the params will be appended to the url (path changes to `/somepath?a=1&b=2` in the url bar), but the page itself does not rerender.

I understand that the constructor is only executed on initial pageload, which explains why it's not grabbing the query params and storing it in the state unless it's a fresh reload.
Is there some way to make the page sensitive to new params being appended by `hashHistory.push()`?

Comment: Please provide some code to see what's the issue

Comment: @RazvanAlex Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the query params in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. When you first route the `/somepath`, `componentDidMount` of `SomeComponent` would be called. Then change to `/somepath?a=1&b=2`, `componentDidUpdate` would be called(at this time `componentDidMount` wouldn't be called).

Refer to [this document](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md). See how it navigates from `/invoices/123` to `/invoices/789`.